# NodeJS - Multiple Await calls to sequentially build an output object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, export-to-csv

I have a process where a user uploads a CSV file, and the CSV file is then read using the CSV2JSON module. I then loop through the lines of the CSV and query multiple web service calls to generate a new CSV file containing the results of the web service calls.

I'm having an issue with the async/await methods to build the output as I need to wait for the service calls to finish to build the output object...

The error I get is:

> await is only valid in async function

How would I use multiple awaits to get the output?

```
const csv2json = require("csvtojson");
const json2csv = require("jsontocsv");
const path = require('path');
const axios = require("axios");

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function getCSVtoJSON(filePath, callback) {
    //set the file parth
    var csvFile = path.join(__dirname + '\\..\\' + filePath);

    try {
        await csv2json()
            .fromFile(csvFile)
            .then((jsonObj) => {
                callback(jsonObj);
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function getWS(endpointURL, par1, par2, callback) {
    try {
        var getURL = 'http://blabla.com/' + endpointURL + '?par1=' + par1 + '&par2=' + par2;

        //Add the request info as config items
        await axios(getURL)
            .then((objReturn) => {
                callback(objReturn.data);
            });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async function processCSV(csvFilename) {
    let sourceCSV = [];
    let objList = [];
    let objOutput = [];
    let par1 = 0;
    let par2 = 0;


    //1st await is to get the csv data
    await getCSVtoJSON(csvFilename, function (csvJSON) {
        sourceCSV = csvJSON;
    });


    //now loop through each CSV line and build the output
    sourceCSV.forEach(function (csvLines) {

        //add the Source Data to the output
        let counter = 0;
        for (const key of Object.keys(csvLines)) {
            newKey = 'source_' + key;
            value = csvLines[key];
            //Start building the output object
            objList[newKey] = value;

            //set the par for the webservice calls
            if (counter == 1) { par1 = value; };
            if (counter == 2) { par2 = value; };
            counter++;
        }

        //Now link the data from web service 1
        await getWS('/call1/', par1, par2, function (returnData) {
            //process returnData and add the results to objList
        });

        //Now link the data from web service 2
        await getWS('/call2/', par1, par2, function (returnData2) {
            //process returnData2 and add the results to objList
        });

        //Now link the data from web service 3
        await getWS('/call3/', par1, par2, function (returnData3) {
            //process returnData3 and add the results to objList
        });

    });  //end loop csv lines

    //Now push the resultline to the main obj and continue with loop 
    objOutput.push(objList);

};

//Now write out the main obj to the result CSV
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix nested methods with async also.  Simplified example:

WILL NOT WORK:

```
async function doAThing() {
  const result = await promiseReturningCall();
  function inner() {
     const innerResult = await anotherPromiseReturningCall();
  }
}
```

WILL WORK:

```
async function doAThing() {
  const result = await promiseReturningCall();
  async function inner() {
     const innerResult = await anotherPromiseReturningCall();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting my head around this - 

I read the CSV file (used await), Loop through each record and call a function that in turn calls a web service to get query data using axios (also used await). Build a array that contains all the data for that single csv request and push it to a new array to write it out to a new csv file using JSONtoCSV

The main array is undefined as it does not get the data.

Comment: would this mean that the foreach function would also need to be async ??    - sourceCSV.forEach(function (csvLines)  >>  sourceCSV.forEach(async function (csvLines)  ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of